# Chrome dev tools - Watch tab - regex

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It is possible to use regular expressions in Watch tab (Sources tab) in Chrome dev tools?

[image]

Comment: I would like to watch any property named, for example, 'name'. So I would like to watch `anyObjectName.name`

Comment: No, there's no such feature.